# PTIJ: Why do we say Mashiach is coming in a carriage?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

Every day we say in Kaddish:

> בַּעֲגָלָא וּבִזְמַן קָרִיב
>
> [May redemption come] in a wagon, quickly.

Whether Mashiach comes in a cloud or a donkey (cf. [Sanhedrin 98a](https://www.sefaria.org/Sanhedrin.98a.13?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)), he’s not coming in a wagon. So why do we daven that he come in a wagon?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: You've been pronouncing it wrong. It's supposed to be prononunced "beigeleh". Moshiach will come with mini bagels.

Comment: @Dov https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5146/list-of-ptij-edits-for-next-season

Comment: Thanks @Alex - got it!

Answer (score 4):

This is one of many references to the concept of Mashiach ben Yosef coming before Mashiach ben Dovid.

As we know, when Yosef revealed himself to his brothers, he sent them back to his father with wagons for transporting his father back to Egypt.

Therefore, Mashiach who comes in a wagon must be referring to Mashiach ben Yosef, as Yosef is the one who sends wagons.

---

With thanks to my wife and brother-in-law for their contributions to this answer.

Comment: Oy! Exactly what I thought before I saw your answer.

Answer (score 1):

See Megillah 31b:

> אמר לפניו רבש"ע במה אדע אמר לו קחה לי עגלה משולשת וגו' אמר לפניו רבש"ע תינח בזמן שבית המקדש קיים בזמן שאין בית המקדש קיים מה תהא עליהם אמר לו כבר תקנתי להם סדר קרבנות כל זמן שקוראין בהן מעלה אני עליהן כאילו מקריבין לפני קרבן ומוחל אני על כל עונותיהם:
>
> Abraham then said before Him: Master of the Universe: “By what shall I know this?” God said to him: “Take Me a carriage of about three years old” (Genesis 15:9). With this, God intimated to Abraham that even if his descendants will sin, they will be able to achieve atonement through sacrificing offerings. Abraham said before Him: Master of the Universe, this works out well when the Temple is standing and offerings can be brought to achieve atonement, but when the Temple will no longer be standing, what will become of them? God said to him: I have already established for them the order of offerings, i.e., the verses of the Torah pertaining to the halakhot of the offerings. Whenever they read those portions, I will deem it as if they sacrificed an offering before Me, and I will pardon them for all of their iniquities.